# What does "kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup" followed by other errors mean?

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel, syslog

I have my terminal always opened (Fedora 22), because all my work I do from there. Sometimes I search some info in browser or just have fun. After 20-30 minutes of browsing (browser starts not from command line) I return to terminal and saw something strange - it was in all tabs of terminal:

```
Message from syslogd@localhost at Jul 17 23:17:19 ...
kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s! [migration/2:21]

Message from syslogd@localhost at Jul 17 23:17:38 ...
kernel:CPU: 2 PID: 21 Comm: migration/2 Not tainted 4.0.7-300.fc22.i686 #1

Message from syslogd@localhost at Jul 17 23:17:39 ...
kernel:Hardware name: LENOVO 20126/123456789, BIOS 5BCN30WW 10/10/2012

Message from syslogd@localhost at Jul 17 23:17:39 ...
kernel:task: f45f0000 ti: f45ec000 task.ti: f45ec000

Message from syslogd@localhost at Jul 17 23:17:39 ...
 kernel:Stack:

 Message from syslogd@localhost at Jul 17 23:17:40 ...
  kernel:Call Trace:

  Message from syslogd@localhost at Jul 17 23:17:40 ...
   kernel: <IRQ>

   Message from syslogd@localhost at Jul 17 23:17:40 ...
    kernel:#000<IRQ> #000868>] do_softirq_own_stack+0x28/0x30#0000xc0 [mac80211]#000c80211]#000014#000es iptable_nat nf_conntrack_localhost#000frag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_kernel#000conntrack#000#000#000#000el:#000_mangle iptable_security#000ul 17 23:17:40#000#000hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_#000eneric#000arc4 s#000d_hda_intel#000rtl8192ce s#000d_hda_co#000#000#000#000�#001#000#000-#000#000#000�s#003�09b3e98>] ip_rcv+0x2e8/0x410#000#000#000#000%#000#000#000localhost.localdomain#000videob#025#000#000#000kernel#000Y#0009#000#000#025#000#000#000_MACHINE_ID#000-#000#000#000#006#000#000#000�'g�p&g�#001#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#020#026#000�#001#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#025#000#000#000_TRANSPORT#0001#025#000#000#000PRIORITY#0002#000#000-#000#000#000#006#000#000#000�'g�p&g�#001#000#000#000#000#000#000#000Pw#003�#006#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000-#000#000#0000r#003��'g�p&g�#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#0008r#003� #000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#000#025#000#000#0006036995285#000#0005#000#000#000 k#003�045c0c0>]...
```

and a bit more stuff like these last long line. Laptop didn't behave like something wrong, it was just this log in all tabs of terminal.

What's this???

Comment: What does `dmesg` command show?

Comment: I didn't find anything in dmesg, I've look at it almost at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the updated kernel; but, this maybe related to your laptop's battery poor performance. This you can be more affirmative by checking ACPI(Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) modules.

When my kernel was updated, I restarted my system and started the new kernel---however it failed to load and the same error messages were sent to the terminal.

```
I reverted back to my old kernel usage, which is still working for me.
```

---

Maybe,not sure but newer kernel modules might have some enhancements which are unable to be supported by the current power source. Like, it needs more power or something.

Also, my laptop's battery performance has declined severely and it needs to be replaced in my case.

**EDIT:** (based on [Nikos Alexandris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13011/nikos-alexandris)'s comment)

You **may** consider replacing your charge source; it **may** have something to do with power management.

Comment: My battery is almost new. I have been used my Lenovo s110 only for a bit more, than half of a year. Probably, problem really in kernel - I had almost all this time fedora 20 and everything was ok

Comment: @Sergius-Actually, you should check about the latest kernel update,I'm not sure if it has updated in your system.If no, then don't know! If yes, then restart with old kernel, it'd would work fine at this stage. And,next, believe me, it has everything to do with your battery/power. Try a battery of your friend's laptop(same model/company)

Comment: The power source point is totally unrelated. Most likely a faulty kernel, aka kernel bug, causes the lockups. This explains why going back to older kernel was sucessful. Also upgrading to a newer kernel would have helped.

Comment: @itconlor - I agree with the first point. But, your second point may not be true. The new update itself caused the lockup, so in case of no further newer version available, OP is left with nothing else. Hence, the suggestion to replace the battery is also perfectly valid, as the battery's perormance is equally responsible for the same.

Comment: I think I experience exactly the very problem described here.  My laptop's battery, after more than 2 years of intensive use, has dropped rapidly and enormously within the last few weeks down to less than 20% of its original capacity. Today, I installed a new battery. I hope the outcome will be no more CPU soft lockups. Will report here.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris - Hope it works. If it helps, please don't forget to upvote the answer!

Comment: After weeks (of waiting for a hardware check and repair), I still think it's related to linux and the battery. I reinstalled Windows and there seems to be no problem, with the same battery. I'll report later on, once I install a new battery.

Comment: Today I received a new laptop battery. A Live-USB Ubuntu version, does not crash (noted, I did not try this very same Live-USB before) anymore (some Live-USB Linux version did crash when launching firefox). My own kernel still crashes. This makes me think that the problem is not a hardware one, at least in my case.

Comment: It seems there can be many reasons for this "kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup" bug. 
 See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1530405  It seems to be happening on various distributions.

Answer (score 1):

It's irrelated to battery.

Indeed, you can find detailed information about these messages. It just means that Linux kernel is handling a task too long to handle other tasks in kernel space. `watchdog` daemon monitor this event and notifies you in login screen and `/etc/messages`.

Just find what is exhausting your CPU.